# can't sent quantity from catalog to shopping cart

Tags: php, web, shopping-cart

I have problem in my web project (shopping cart). i can't send quantity on my product order
this is screen shoot my web

when i click 'BELI' it can't send a quantity to my database.

this is my piece script:

```
<td align="left">
<font face="verdana" size="2" color="#666666">
<select name='jml'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    </select>
    </font>
</td>

<td align="center">
    <a  href="#" title="Klik untuk membeli" onClick="konfirm(<? echo $id_produk; ?>)"><img src="./img/beli.jpg" border="0"></a>
</td>
```

and this is my php piece script in other file.

```
if($_SESSION['user_id'])
{
    include "./include/conn.php";
    $iduser=$_SESSION['user_id'];
    $idbrg=$_GET['id_produk'];
    $jml=$_GET['jml'];
    $tanggal;

    //check the status of the customer
    $view=mysql_db_query($db,"select * from laporan where iduser='$iduser'",$koneksi);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($view)){
        $status=$row['status'];
    }
...

$query=mysql_db_query($db,"insert into keranjang_belanja(jumlah,id_produk,id_user,tanggal) values('$jml','$idbrg','$iduser','$tanggal')",$koneksi);
```

please help me to fix it. and i'm sory for my english limitation

Answer (score 0):

First of all You are using wrong function

```
mysql_db_query
```

Use

```
mysql_query
```

instead

Something like this

```
$view=mysql_query("select * from laporan where iduser='$iduser'");
```

Secondly what method you are using in form is it GET or POST?